# JavaFX combobox displays wrong number of items when updating Observable list

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a combobox whose items can change. When changing the items of said combobox to have less items then previously, the combobox still displays the same amount of item fields, the 'extra' fields being blank.

Like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkMf5.png

Here is the code I use to change the combobox.

```
@FXML private ComboBox<Task> taskComboBox;
private ObservableList<TaskDTO> tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public Foo() {
    taskComboBox.setItems(tasks);
}

@FXML
private void loadTaskComboBox(int i) {
    tasks.clear();
    tasks.addAll(getTasks(i));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

ComboBox API:

> By default, when the popup list is showing, the maximum number of rows
>   visible is 10, but this can be changed by modifying the
>   `visibleRowCount` property. If the number of items in the ComboBox is
>   less than the value of `visibleRowCount`, then the items size will be
>   used instead so that the popup list is not exceedingly long.

But on the other hand, if the number of items is shrinking, the ListView (popup content) will not shrink. But you can adjust the [`visibleRowCountProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#visibleRowCountProperty--) to adjust the number of visible items.

Comment: Changing the visibleRowCountProperty after I updated the list has no effect and still displays more items then my list has. :(

Comment: @TomNijs faintly remember that there was a bug related to dynamically changing the items, might be related (forgot the id, though)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the ComboBox API itself does not offer much more.. you could try creating your own ComboBox skin or search the JavaFX bug tracker (https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) and file a bug if there is none for this issue.

Comment: I submitted a bug report. Thanks for all the replies.